# How can I create a batch file for SQLPlus?

Tags: sqlplus

I need to create a batch file, i.e., `batch.bat`.

When we execute this file:

1. It will open SQLPlus
2. It will call a file called `file1.sql`.

`file1.sql` contains the creation and insertion scripts for a particular user.

I have `file.sql`, but what I need to know is, how do I create a batch file to perform this function?

Comment: Andri's answer (below) is correct. Why not accept it?

Answer (score 5):

A little test script (stored in file named `test.sql`):

```
select 1 from dual;

exit;
```

... and to execute it:

```
sqlplus user/password @test.sql
```

Comment: i need to create a new schema in that batch file itself..
so, pls tel me what is the command to creat new schema?

Comment: with CREATE USER: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8003.htm#i2065278

Comment: I tried exactly this and it doesn't work within a batch file on my computer.  I can, however, type this on the command line and it works.  In a batch file I get the message "ERROR 6 initializing SQL*Plus" and it says something about not finding a message file and recommends I set ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Okay, just noticed that in my batch file I was using a configurable variable to set the sqlplus command name... and I named it "SQLPLUS", which is apparently used by Oracle to find sqlplus files.  Bugger.