# Use values from a sql query in batch script

Tags: oracle, batch-file

Lets say I have a query as follows:

```
Select name, age from employee where id=&id;
```

Is it possible to run the query in a batch file and use the returned values in Jscript inside a batch script?

Lets say the query returns "Tom Smith" as name and "33" as age.

Its is possible to use the values in the batch script? if yes please can you give me an example?

i am refering to Oracle database server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a utility called SQL*Plus (command: `sqlplus`) is available for that kind of thing.

See [http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ)*Plus_FAQ

and [How can I create a batch file for SQLPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881115/how-can-i-create-a-batch-file-for-sqlplus)

... so you can retrieve the value into environment variables using a `For` :
`for /f %%a in ('sqlplus ...') do SET ...`